# Vercel build failed because of Github Package

Tags: javascript, typescript, vercel, github-packages

I have React app, where I use a package with contracts (only *.d.ts files with interfaces) that is deployed in [Github Packages](https://github.com/goskan93/trello-clone-contracts).
My react app is deployed with Vercel. Unfortunally I get an error while build in Vercel
[image: error in build]

I install the package like it shows [here](https://vercel.com/guides/using-private-dependencies-with-vercel), so I have in my `package.json`

```
 "@goskan93/trello-clone-contracts": "git+https://<my-username>:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/goskan93/trello-clone-contracts.git"
```

I have set `GITHUB_TOKEN` in env variables in Vercel.

I have tried clean github cache, did not work.

Locally the build is working.